# Can I have mip levels that are not the standard / 2 for each level?

Tags: vulkan

When you create a mipmapped image in Vulkan you create an image and specify the number of mips. Then you copy each mip level with a transfer to the corresponding mip level. The standard way to calculate each mip level is to divide the source mip size by two and round down to the closest integer. This is done repeatedly until the max image extent reaches 1.

I'm assuming that Vulkan "assumes" that each mip level will be according to this formula. But let's say I have a 516 width original image. I divide by two and get 258. But let's say I want this mip to be 260 instead of 258. I make a 260 width image and copy it into mip level [1]. However from Vulkan's point of view this mip level image is only 258, the sizes wouldn't match, and it would sample from the wrong memory.

What does Vulkan assume in this regard? Can you specify certain sizes for the mips?

Answer (score 4):

Vulkan does not "assume" the size of mipmap levels. The size of mipmap levels [is defined based on the size of the image](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-khr-extensions/html/chap12.html#resources-image-mip-level-sizing). Given the base level's size (where `n` is 0), the dimensions of any lower mipmap level is computed as follows:

> dim<sub>n+1</sub> = max(⌊dim<sub>n</sub>/2⌋, 1)

You cannot decide what the sizes of mipmap levels are, outside of your ability to control the base level's size.

Comment: From ChatGPT: "In Vulkan, the sizes of mip levels for images are typically divided by 2 from the previous level. This is the default behavior and follows the standard mipmapping technique.

However, Vulkan provides flexibility in specifying custom mip level sizes through the `VkImageCreateInfo` structure. By setting the `mipLevels` field to a value greater than 1 and providing the desired dimensions for each mip level in the `width`, `height`, and `depth` fields, you can define your own mip level sizes." Apparently Directx12 allows this too. Were you aware of this? Is it an extension?

Comment: From ChatGPT: "To specify custom mip level sizes, you need to create an image with the VK_IMAGE_CREATE_MUTABLE_FORMAT_BIT flag and provide an array of VkSubresourceLayout structures that define the layout of each mip level. Each VkSubresourceLayout structure holds the offset , size , and rowPitch values for a specific mip level."

Comment: @Zebrafish: Please do not cite ChatGPT as though its job is to generate facts. I do not intend to spend any time debunking whatever garbage an LLM generates.

Comment: I still have this problem of creating an image in block compression format whose size isn't a multiple of 4 at the first level. I know Vulkan allows this but many applications and APIs don't such as DirectX and Unity don't according to the spec. How are you supposed to create an image from a lower detail mip level that isn't a multiple of 4?

Comment: @Zebrafish: I don't understand what you're asking about. You seem to be asking how to do something in Vulkan that Vulkan just lets you do. If you're using a non-Vulkan API, then ask about that API. Or don't; if the API doesn't allow you to do so, then you're *not* "supposed" to be able to do it. Again, the kind of thing you're talking about is generally handled with specialized memory stuff like sparse residency, *not* with the kind of thing you're trying to do.